Equivalent condition to positive homogeneity for sublinear function
The Wikipedia entry for Sublinear function states that the two following conditions are equivalent when defining a sublinear function:
Let X be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Let $p: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function from the vector space to the reals. Then
$$
p(rx) = rp(x) \; \forall r > 0, \forall x \in X \quad \text{if and only if} \quad p(rx) \leq rp(x) \; \forall r > 0, \forall x \in X
$$
Does anyone know how to prove this (specifically the backwards implication)? I don't see a proof in the Wikipedia entry.
